# deleting child explicitly by using parent.setChilds(null)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 objects `Parent` and `Child` associated with a one to many mapping.

Now I want to delete all the childs of `Parent`.
I used the following code but it does not have any effect.

```
 //start tx
     Parent p = getFromDb();
        p.setChilds(null) ; explicitly setting to null so that childs get deleted
        session.merge(p);
  //commit tx
```

I have the following in my configurations:

```
<set name="myChilds" inverse="true" lazy="false" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="parentId" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.xyz.MyChild" />
        </set>
```

Am not getting any exception but childs not get deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `myChilds` collection is marked as the inverse association of the many-to-one from child to parent. This means that Hibernate uses the other side of the association to decide if the association exists or not.

You should thus set the `child.parent` to `null` rather than nulling (or emptying, which is much cleaner than nulling) the set of children.

This, however, won't be sufficient. Breaking an association between a parent and its children doesn't kill the children. It just makes them orphan. If you want to delete them, you must call `session.delete()` on every child.

Finally, merge is not useful at all here. The goal of merge is to copy the state of a detached entity to its attached version. Your parent entity is already attached.

You seem to have missed many parts of the very good explanations in the [Hibernate reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/). Read it again.

Comment: @JB.Thanks for reply so can i do child.setParent(null).So this will break the refrence and make child orphan.How can i delete orphans?Also can i skip merge in my code as my entity is already attached?

Comment: I think you can do this with `cascade="all-delete-orphan"` in the mapping. See [Example 21: Parent/Child](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html) of the Hibernate Reference. Anyway, it will favour  inmensely readability to use `delete()` as JB said. And yes, you can entirely skip `merge` if the entity is already attached. Those changes will be flushed to the database when the Hibernate Session gets closed.

Comment: See my answer : "you must call session.delete() on every child". "merge is not useful at all", which means that you should reove the merge line.

Answer (score 0):

We need to see more of your mapping, explicitly the child mapping.

My theory is that your relationship is by-directional, so you need to set the parent reference in each child to null.

Another possibility is that you are setting the wrong set to null, given that your mapping shows the child set to have a name of `myChilds` but your setter is just `setChilds`.  If your `setChilds` method actually sets the `myChilds` property than this is not the case...

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate associate for your parent entity one collection of child elements. If you set null this relation get broken but not delete children physically from db. You can solve this issue if `clean()` the collection/list/set that presents your children elements in parent class. As you know the objects in list stored by reference and if clean up real entity that present each child element.